# Create SharePoint Group to manage other SharePoint groups?

Tags: permissions

Is it possible with SharePoint 2010 to create a SharePoint group, AND assign it permissions to manage all the other groups?

We have created a new sps group and gave it 'all permissions' but yet this group is still unable to manage the other groups or memberships to it.  How can we accomplish this? Is this possible?

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into the other group propertites and set the Group Owner to the group you just created.

Comment: Thank you for response however, I do not want to explicitly set the 2nd group as the owner of the first group.  Can I allow the 2nd group to manage the 1st group through permissions? ty

Comment: They have to be members of the group that owns the desired group in order to modify the membership of the desired group.

Comment: I have a similar issue. I need to add a group to Distribution group. Is this possible? I can add another group as a member to a Security group but I can't do the same with Distribution Group, why?